# How do you get the accuracy for individual class type in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am training an tensorflow.keras deep learning model with two ouputs for binary classification.

```
  model=tf.keras.Sequential(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)) 
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation="sigmoid"))
```

When I run fit or evaluate I only get one number for accuracy, how can you split the accuracy based on the output? Furthermore, does the model try to minimize the loss function based on both of the outputs? Is this good practice or is it better to run two separate models?

Comment: Have you tried `tf.math.confusion_matrix`? Will that solve your purpose?